# Draw text on canvas dont work with mutable bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, bitmap, mutable

I want to use custom markers on google maps in my Android app.
For this I have a method, which creates me Bitmaps. Each Bitmap is a marker including special text on it. 
I have done this and it works ok on my 2.3.3 Android. But on other devices it crashes, cause I dont use `mutable Bitmaps`. 
I changed my code to mutable Bitmaps, but now the text isn't visible, just the marker bitmap without text.

My method:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.marker);

Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTypeface(tf);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(context, 8));

Rect textRect = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(markerText, 0, markerText.length(), textRect);
// THIS LINE IS NEW FOR MUTABLE
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

if(textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4)){
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(context, 7));
}
int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;
int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

canvas.drawText(markerText, xPos, yPos, paint);

return  bm;
```

What I am doing wrong? I just add the line with mutable.

best regards

Comment: have you tried returning the mutableBitmap instead of bm ?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Answer is marked as solved. thx guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns the immutable bitmap that you obtained using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.

You must return the mutable bitmap you drawed on:

```
return mutableBitmap;
```